# Firebase Auth: Can not get a new token using refresh token REST

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, google-api, firebase-authentication, cors

Im following this to obtain a token from a refresh token:https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token

```js
  let response = await axios.post(`https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=${FIREBASE_CONFIG.apiKey}&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=${refreshToken}`,
    {}, {
      data: qs,
      headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    }
  );
```

It was working in the past but now it's not working.
Have this error in the Chrome console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image]

Comment: What other headers is axios adding to the request? Check by inspecting the request in the Network pane in devtools. Change your frontend code to remove any additional headers axios is adding. Or else instead make the request using `fetch()`, which gives you complete control directly over the headers. I say all that because the error in the question shows the browser’s doing a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, and a POST to `https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token` with only a `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header wouldn’t trigger a preflight

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) is right, the axios instance indeed has few HTTP headers meant for other purposes. After use a clean axios instance, the error is going away. Nevertheless, the error return from googleapis could be a lot more self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

I have recently seen your question.
Maybe my suggestion below will be helpful

```
const url : string = `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=${environment.apiKey}`;
    
const body : any = {
    grant_type : 'refresh_token',
    refresh_token : this.userValue.refresh_token
}
    
return this.http.post<any>(url, body, {withCredentials : false});
```

regards